# Love2d iOS Xcode how to set to non debug mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, love2d

I'm testing my platform game in Xcode with the simulator and my iPhone device and I want to know how to set it to run at full speed ie non debug mode? It currently runs at only 10 fps (!) so I'm hoping that is not the final speed since I heard Love2d is supposed to be fast. At the moment it's the most basic platform game with zero objects or enemies (not even platforms, only the floor) so I don't see why it would be slow.

It of course runs super fast in the device simulators in xcode and also as a .love file on my computer so I'm not sure what the problem is there.

I tried edit scheme in xcode and changing it from Debug to Release but it's still just as slow.

Comment: So the only place your app is slow is on your physical device? It might help to know the specs, etc. and if you've tried it on any other device.

Comment: Yes that's the only place. I'm just interested to know how to set it to full speed mode. I remember with React Native it would be launched always in a slow debug mode unless you specifically set it to full release mode. The speed difference was huge. Not sure how to do that in love2d with iOS.

Not sure how my device specs affect the method for setting love2d to non debug mode in xcode.

Comment: With Xcode `Debug` builds should be almost the same speed as `Release`. If it's horribly slow on your device then something else is wrong, or the device simply isn't fast enough to efficiently run the app.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I wanted to know. I guess there must be something wrong with my code then since other apps run fine on the device.